# Regular expressions - only match when the middle part doesn't match some string

Tags: regex, parsing

The title may sound a little complicated, so let me show a simplified example. I have a test string like this one:

```
A ... 
aaa 
... Z

A ... 
bbb 
... Z

A ... 
ccc 
... Z

A ... 
cxc 
... Z

A ... 
ccc 
... Z

A ... 
cxc 
... Z
```

If I want to match all A-Z sections, that's easy:

```
(?s)A.*?Z
```

If I want to match all A-Z sections without "c" in the middle, that's easy too:

```
(?s)A[^c]*?Z
```

But what I actually want to do is match all A-Z sections without "ccc" in the middle. I tried lookahead assertions:

```
(?s)A(?!.*ccc).*?Z
```

But that only matches the last A-Z section because all the others do in fact have "ccc" somewhere after them.

So, can it be done somehow and in a single regular expression? Matching all A-Z sections in one step and removing the ones with "ccc" in the second step is not an option unfortunately.

As you probably suspect it's an HTML parsing question but I simplified it to separate out the problem.

Comment: How does the last expression *not* do what you want?

Comment: It only matches the 6th section, but not the 1st, 2nd and 4th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex requires some modifications:

```
(?s)A(?:(?!ccc).)*?Z
```

`(?!ccc)` is a negative lookahead that asserts `A` is not followed by `ccc`. The `.` after the lookahead is doing all the matching. It advances through the text one character at a time, making sure that each position is not followed by a `ccc`.

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eG1vT8/2)

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much. I think the "\n?" at the end can just be removed, but that's not really important. The expression works, answer accepted.

Comment: @RafałG.: Yeah, you're right. That's not really required. I've edited it out. Glad to have helped!

Comment: Clean and efficient fix, an old trick but never out of fashion. :) +1